# Find in Vector of a Struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, find

I made the following program where there is a struct

```
struct data
{
   int integers; //input of integers
   int times; //number of times of appearance
}
```

and there is a vector of this struct

```
std::vector<data> inputs;
```

and then I'll get from a file an integer of current_int

```
std::fstream openFile("input.txt")
int current_int; //current_int is what I want to check if it's in my vector of struct (particularly in inputs.integers)
openFile >> current_int;
```

and I wanna check if current_int is already stored in my vector inputs. 
I've tried researching about finding data in a vector and supposedly you use an iterator like this:

```
it = std::find(inputs.begin(),inputs.end(),current_int)
```

but will this work if it's in a struct? Please help.

Comment: it's unclear what current_int represents... how do you want to match it to a struct (which contains *two* integers)?

Comment: just edited it I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 8):

There are [two variants of `find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

- `find()` searches for a plain value.  In you case you have a vector of `data`, so the values passed to `find()` should be `data`.
- `find_if()` takes a predicate, and returns the first position where the predicates returns true.

Using the latter, you can easily match one field of your struct:

```
auto it = std::find_if(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), 
                       [current_int] (const data& d) { 
                          return d.integers == current_int; 
                       });
```

Note that the above uses a C++11 lambda function.  Doing this in earlier versions of C++ requires you to create a functor instead.