# Trying to find a string inside a vector of a class

Tags: c++

first of all excuse me for my English, is not my mother tongue.
Ok, so in university, they just teach me vectors in c++. I'm working on a project, where i have a bag class and a trinket class. 
I'm trying, in a function, to search into the bag if certain trinket exist, if yes, returns the index of the trinket and, if not, returns -1.
How can i find inside vector collection; if certain trinket exist and return it index inside the vector ?
**Notes:**

- vector collection is a private attribute of class Bag.
- class Trinket, have name, weight and value private attributes.
- I've try to do this, but doesn't work :

  ```
      int Bag::searchTrinket(string name){
          vector<Trinket>::iterator it =find(colleccion.begin(),colleccion.end(), name);
          int pos = 0;
          if(it != colleccion.end()){

             cout << "Trinket found in position : ";
             pos = distance(coleccion.begin(), it); 
             cout << pos << endl;
          } else{
           return -1; 
           }
       }
  ```

  In advance, thanks so much!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What is the behaviour you observe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925349/find-in-vector-of-a-struct

Comment: I get this when i try to compile:
 ERROR: No match for "operator=="(operands type are "Trinket" and "const std::basic_string<char> ") . I am really new to programming, so i dont understand this.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_if), not plain `std::find` (unless you have an overloaded `operator==` which takes a `std::string` as argument).

Comment: Given the possible dup, are you using C++11 or not? If not, [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) includes an example of using a functor rather than a lambda.

Comment: We are not allowed to use struct in this assignment. Also, they haven't taught yet.

Comment: `struct foo {...}` is basically just `class foo {public: ...}`, so the dup can be used, if you are allowed lambdas.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i'll try to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You have a vector of `Trinket` objects, not a vector of `std::string` values, so you can't use `std::find()`.  Use `std::find_if()` instead, so you can specify how to reach the desired string within each `Trinket`.

Also, `searchTrinket()` is not returning anything if the string is found, so the return value is undefined.

Try something like this:

```
/* assuming:
class Trinket
{
private:
    std::string name;
    ...
public:
    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    ...
};
*/

struct hasName
{
    std::string &m_name;
    hasName(std::string &name) : m_name(name) {}
    bool operator()(const Trinket &t) const { return (t.getName() == m_name); }
};

int Bag::searchTrinket(std::string name)
{
    std::vector<Trinket>::iterator it = std::find_if(colleccion.begin(), colleccion.end(), hasName(name));
    if (it != colleccion.end())
    {
        int pos = std::distance(coleccion.begin(), it); 
        std::cout << "Trinket found at position : " << pos << std::endl;
        return pos; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Trinket not found" << std::endl;
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

If you are using C++11 or later, and are allowed to use a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), try this instead:

```
auto it = std::find_if(colleccion.begin(), colleccion.end(),
                       [&name](auto &t) { return (t.getName() == name); });
```